# Streaming audio in A-frame

Tags: aframe, audio-streaming, webvr

I am building a multi-user experience in A-frame using NAF, and I have some positional audio containing music tracks in different points of the scene. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to make it that the music is listened simultaneously by all the connected users. It is very important that they are positional, since I need several audio sources in the scene. At the moment, the tracks start when you enter the experience, so each person hears them from the start when they access the scene. This is the file that I'm using right now: https://glitch.com/~indigo-roomy-supermarket

I tried with the broadcast-component, but didn't manage. I thought of trying a workaround using a stream of twitch and hiding the video, trying to project it to a primitive, but also doesn't work so far (just managed to attach it to a div over the scene, I can hide the video but the audio would never be positional). Here the file where I tried it (not networked, but it should be the same): https://glitch.com/~twitchtest-01  I know that there's the option of connecting vimeo to a-frame using this: https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component  but the audio itself is not positional, so it doesn't really solve my problem (also, I don't know if it would work with vimeo live).

If somebody knows a way to do this, I would greatly appreciate if you can share your wisdom. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's easy.

Assuming you have streaming audio servers at your disposal [like this](https://schollz.com/blog/stream/) then the way I would approach this, is:

- fetch an audio stream and once the download returns, get the source buffer
- override the source buffer of your positional audio element (something like `this.el.getObject3D('sound').children[0].source.buffer`) with the newly created audio buffer.

This might work.

If it doesn't, then create you own audio element component by using positional ThreeJS sound directly with [setMediaStreamSource](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/positionalaudio-setmediastreamsource-with-webrtc-question-not-hearing-any-sound/14301).

My assessment would be that this takes several days just to prototype alone. Having said that, I am pretty sure it's doable.